# Does C add '\0' when you pass a literal string as an argument in a function?

Tags: c, string

For instance, if I write:

```
void function(char *k){ printf("%s",k);}
```

and call it like this:

```
function("hello");
```

does the code translate that string to: "hello\0" ? Or I'm the one who has to add it?

Comment: It does. `hello` is in memory stored with trailing zero, `"hello\0"`.

Comment: no - the 0 is added when the literal is declared, not when its passed to a function.

Comment: It doesn't have to be passed to a function, it's just the literal, see `sizeof("hello")`. But note that literals can be used to initialize an array, like `char no_nul[5] = "hello";`

Comment: Note that if you do `char no_nul[5] = "hello";`, as the name `no_nul` implies, you will not get a `\0` when passing it into the function, or really doing anything with that character array. You will only get the first 5 characters.

Comment: @o11c But that's a mean example: With `char no_nul[3] = "hello";` you would only get the first three. But with `char with_nul[6] = "hello";` you would get all characters in the literal, including the `'\0'`.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider With `char no_nul[3] = "hello"` you get an error.

Comment: Do a `printf("%zu\n", sizeof "Hello");` and become enlightened. ;-)

Comment: @melpomene From the n1570 draft, 6.7.9/21 (initialization): "If there are [...] fewer characters in a string literal used to initialize an array of known size than there are elements in the array, the remainder of the aggregate shall be
initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration." gcc 7.3.0 throws a warning with `const char s1[1] = "12";`. I find it surprising that there is none with a 2-character array.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider "*No initializer shall attempt to provide a value for an object not contained within the entity being initialized.*" and "*An array of character type may be initialized by a character string literal, optionally enclosed in braces. Successive characters of the character string literal (including the terminating **null character if there is room** or if the array is of unknown size) initialize the elements of the array.*" Omitting the null character by specifying a smaller array is explicitly allowed.

Comment: @melpomene I see, I quoted the opposite case (string literal is too short). Maybe you are right. What do other compilers say?

Comment: @melpomene I see that MSVC warns about "array bounds overflow"... do you think that other compilers, too, actually write beyond the array's last element? That never occurred to me.

Answer (score 5):

In C (And C++), when you do
`const char* mystr = "Hello";`, the compiler will generate the following in (read-only) RAM:

```
0x7fff2fe0: 'H'
0x7fff2fe1: 'e'
0x7fff2fe2: 'l'
0x7fff2fe3: 'l'
0x7fff2fe4: 'o'
0x7fff2fe5: '\0'
```

Then, the compiler will replace

```
const char* mystr = "Hello";
```

with

```
const char* mystr = 0x7fff2fe0;
```

For your usage, your code will turn into

```
function(0x7fff2fe0)
```

Simple as that.

On a compiler level, all string literals have type `const char[N]`, where the char array is an array that contains all of the written characters, followed by a `\0`. The `char[N]` has a length `N` that is 1 + the length of the string you write (`char[6]` for `"Hello"`). More information can be found in the [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/string_literal), where they also use the string "Hello" as an example. Thus, `sizeof("Hello") == 6`, and `"Hello"[5] == '\0'` (Yes, `"Hello"[5]` is legal, remember, `"Hello"` has type `const char[6]`). We see this information exemplified in the following:

```
printf("%d\n", sizeof("Hello")); // 6
const char[] str = "Hello"; // Casts from const char[6] to const char[6]
                            // Resulting in a copy of all 6 bytes
printf("%d\n", sizeof(str)); // 6
const char* str2 = "Hello"; // Casts from const char[6] to const char*
printf("%d\n", sizeof(str2)); // 4 on a 32bit system, 8 on a 64bit system
```

Do note, when casting to a pointer, that you get some pointer e.g. `0x7fff2fe0` to an array of characters that is **not** modifiable - attempting to modify the data pointed at `0x7fff2fe0` or `0x7fff2fe5` is explicitly undefined behavior. This status is commonly represented with `const`; by writing `const`, the compiler will correctly complain if you try to edit it.

As an additional note, by writing

```
char[] myarr = "Hello";
```

You will create a duplicate stack-allocated character array named `myarr`, and *that* array may be modified. `myarr` will indeed still contain `\0` and have a size of 6 `char`s, in particular, `myarr` will have type `char[6]`, with `sizeof(myarr) == 6`.

Comment: strlen is distinct from the size of the character array.

Comment: @rmoro I've fixed the link.

Comment: @NicholasPipitone cppreference.com is not the specification. That would be the official ISO C standard.

Comment: @rmoro No, it won't.

Comment: @rmoro `x[5]` is definitely not undefined behavior. It will give ASCII code \0. Now I don't know if somewhere in there it guarantees that it is the integer zero, but x[5] == '\0' is true. I find it likely that \0 -> 0 is guaranteed as well.

Comment: @rmoro: No, it won't. `x[5]` is valid and guaranteed to be `\0`.

Comment: @melpomene Fair enough, updated (On use of the word 'specification').

Comment: @rmoro strlen != sizeof. Try to find out the difference.

Comment: You should at least mention that it's non-modifiable, and might be merged with other literals.

Comment: @Deduplicator "it's non-modifiable" --> A _string literal_ might be modifiable.  To attempt to do so is UB.  It might work, might not.  It's UB.

Comment: @chux It's non-modifiable like all other constants. On some platforms, the implementation will even (often) detect violation. On others, the error results in silent corruption, with possible interesting results further down the line.

Answer (score 4):

From the [C11 Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 
Section 6.4.5 *String Literals*, Paragraph 6 (p. 71):

> In  translation  phase  7,  a  byte  or  code  of  value  zero  is  appended  to  each  multibyte
>   character sequence that results from a string literal or literals.
>   78)
>   The multibyte character
>   sequence  is  then  used  to  initialize  an  array  of  static  storage  duration  and  length  just
>   sufficient  to  contain  the  sequence

Answer (score 4):

A string literal already includes a terminating `\0` by itself, regardless of what you do with that literal. `"hello"` is always a `char [6]` array of `h`, `e`, `l`, `l`, `o` and `\0`, by definition. So, the fact that you "pass it to a function" is completely inconsequential here.

There's no need to add anything.

Answer (score 1):

String literals are not passed to the functions only the pointer to the first character. The referenced object will have all the chars + terminating zero.